# How to enable access to subsite only to certain users or groups?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, security

I created an intranet site based on Sharepoint Foundation 2010 which is based on mixed authentication (Windows and Form Based).

It has a main site where all logged users have access and there are different subsites. I am trying to set the subsites in a way that, by default, their access is denied to all logged users.

Users can access to the subsite only if an administrator has granted them access to read or read/write.

Unfortunately I cannot reach the desired result. I have tried to delete the automatically created Visitors group from the subsite but all users continue to have access to the subsite too.

Do you have any idea how can I reach the desired behavior?

Comment: you must add user group to the particular subsite as you are breaking the inheritance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to delete any groups for this, you just have to break the permission inheritance for the website you want secure. After breaking inheritance you can remove all unwanted permissions and give permission to the users/groups you want.

Comment: @Flo I am not able to find how to break inheritance for a sub site. Can you point me where to do it?

Comment: I found how to remove inheritance in the Site Assets of main site. I remove all groups there except the site owner, but users continue to access to sub site even if I didn't give them the access

Comment: The problem was that I added read permission to the whole group at Web Management level. I remove that and now I can fine tune permission on main site and sub sites.

Comment: I Have another problem. I have a root web which user1 has no permisson at all. I created a sub site with break permission (remove inheritance) and gave user1 permission to this sub site. but user1 gets Access denied when he browses to the subsite. any idea? thanks

Comment: Start a new question for your issue. No one will see it here.